# base64 decoding to URL, reward possible

Tags: base64

First off thanks in advance for any help with this.  I've found the following 3 links in base64 but can't for the life of me figure out how to get them down to the URL they point to or the 6 digits they need to create.  Again any help is extremely appreciated and has the potential for a reward.

EswtC4h5UKXQVcClfN/r3QfzS4A=

rtxZRawESMtN4eLIyCnwg+bjaqE=

iEJ/aFz+jaDOaJon72bu4eL9FUc=

Comment: `"but can't for the life of me"`, less ok ?!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Google I/O community on G+ for solutions https://plus.google.com/communities/105113874753230740413

Comment: In the end, what was the "manual" way to decypher these Base64 encoded SHA1s without a password cracker like hashcat?